# Please Help Dual GPU Graphics Drivers Debian 12

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, multi-monitor, radeon

I have decided to switch over to Linux after years of using Windows. I have a 6 monitor set up paired with a 3090 and RX 5700 XT, the only reason I use the XT is because the 3090 only supports up to 4 displays. (F NVDA)

Upon installation all my monitors were displaying just fine, however, after downloading the NVDA driver my two monitors hooked up to the XT are displaying a black screen with a white _. I have downloaded the AMD graphics drivers but still nothing.

Is there any fix to this problem? Also when I start the OS or shut it down the line of code showing everything is [OK] only displays on the two 5700 XT monitors.